# Search and remove Duplicates in a List

Tags: c#

In this post [Other Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450274/search-directory-for-files-that-start-with-access-and-then-search-that-file) I used the programmers suggestion of `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> IdentityLines = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();`  to collect multiple string values within certain files of a directory.  I now want to remove the duplicate values from that list.  Any idea how I can do that in C#?  Thanks

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752/remove-duplicates-from-a-listt-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static List<T> RemoveDuplicates<T>(List<T> inputList) 
{ 
    Dictionary<T, int> uniqueStore = new Dictionary<T, int>(); 
    List<T> finalList = new List<T>(); 

    foreach (string currValue in inputList) 
    { 
        if (!uniqueStore.ContainsKey(currValue)) 
        { 
            uniqueStore.Add(currValue, 0); 
            finalList.Add(currValue); 
        } 
    } 
    return finalList; 
}
```

http://www.kirupa.com/net/removingDuplicates.htm

If you want to return an `IEnumerable` instead, change your return type to `IEnumerable<T>` and `yield` `return` currValue instead of adding it to the final list.

Comment: On that link you posted after this line List<string> result = removeDuplicates(input);  What would the foreach loop look like if I wanted to write to a text file?  Here is my guess but I get an error on foreach stating cannot convert type string to System.Collections.Generic.List<string>

foreach (List<string> lines in result)
        {
                                StreamWriter fs = File.AppendText(@"C:\Logs\" + "UserSummary" + ".log");
                                fs.Write(lines.Value + "\r\n");
                                fs.Close();
                            }

Comment: I think you want `foreach(string s in result)`, based on the error you provided.

Comment: Hi Robert- If I do that then how do I write the value from s?  s doesn't have s.value that I can use at fs.Write();

Comment: Well, I can't see you're code, but it's definitely *not* `foreach(list<string> lines in result)`. It *might* be `foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> p in result)`

Comment: Hi Robert-  Your last post is close but throws an error on foreach stating connot convert type string to Systems.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>

Comment: Ah, see it still expects a string, which means that the list you are providing it (the `result` variable) contains strings, not key value pairs. Check your code carefully.

Answer (score 5):

Use the Distinct method that is found with Linq. Here is an example using a list of ints.

`Using System.Linq;`

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 5 };
List<int> distinctList = list.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old question, but here's how I do this:

```
var inputKeys = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                          {
                              new KeyValuePair<string, string>("myFirstKey", "one"),
                              new KeyValuePair<string, string>("myFirstKey", "two"),
                              new KeyValuePair<string, string>("mySecondKey", "one"),
                              new KeyValuePair<string, string>("mySecondKey", "two"),
                              new KeyValuePair<string, string>("mySecondKey", "two"),
                          };
 var uniqueKeys = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

 //get rid of any duplicates
 uniqueKeys.AddRange(inputKeys.Where(keyPair => !uniqueKeys.Contains(keyPair)));

 Assert.AreEqual(inputKeys.Count(), 5);
 Assert.AreEqual(uniqueKeys.Count(), 4);
```